# Win32 fallocate(fd, FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE|FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE, ...) API example?

Tags: winapi, sparse-file

Linux has `fallocate(fd, FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE|FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE, ...)` to punch a hole into a file, i.e. deallocate the blocks given and make the file a "sparse file".

But how can I do that with the Win32 API? Does anyone have an example for Win32, which is the Win equivalent to Linux `fallocate(fd, FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE|FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE, 1048576, 2097152);`?

Comment: [Sparse File Operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/sparse-file-operations).

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011508/how-to-create-a-sparse-file-on-ntfs and @RbMm has given [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77506098/code-example-how-to-find-holes-in-sparse-files-with-win32-api/77510954#comment136646893_77506098) in your previous question.

Comment: No, the last question was about QUERY for sparse file holes. THIS question is about DEALLOCATING blocks in a file, aka make a hole in a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DWORD dwBytesReturned;
FILE_ZERO_DATA_INFORMATION FZDI;
FZDI.FileOffset.QuadPart      = 1048576;
FZDI.BeyondFinalZero.QuadPart = 1048576 + 2097152;
int res = DeviceIoControl(hFile, FSCTL_SET_ZERO_DATA, &FZDI, sizeof(FZDI), NULL, 0, &dwBytesReturned, NULL);
```

Comment: Those integer literals really should have an `ll`-suffix. Otherwise, you're running into the risk of integer overflow. Signed integer overflow is UB.